# How to locate objects in SSMS

Tags: ssms

I am trying to find certain, tables, procedures etc.. using the Find and Replace option in SSMS. However, it doesn't appear to locate tables or anything. For example, if I wanted to see if a table called 'formulaone' exist within a certain database using the feature, it wouldnt find it, although I know the table exist. I appreciate the Find and Replace selects 'Find in Files', but there is no other option.
[image]

It has been suggested that I can filter through object explorer. However, I don't have that option, see image. Do I need to be running a newer version of SSMS. I'm currently running version 18.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Find and Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/find-and-replace?view=sql-server-ver16) in SSMS searches text in your *open tab(s)* or within *files*, it does **not** search objects in your databases.

> Use the Find and Replace dialog box to locate text within a file and optionally replace it.

In SSMS you can filter the list in Object Explorer by right-clicking on the `Tables`, `Views`, `Procedures` etc section and choosing `Filter`

[image]

Or just search for your object within the database:

```
select *
from sys.objects
where [name] like '%some text to match%';
```

Comment: Hi @Stu, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question because I can' t see the option you suggested to filter in SSMS

Comment: @Patterson That's because you're not looking in the right place (*you can filter the list in Object Explorer by right-clicking on the `Tables`, `Views`, `Procedures` etc sections*), you find the option on the specific object names in the explorer, not the top level server connection, [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QhMP.png)

Comment: Is it possible to filter from the database as well#

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what that means

Comment: I mean, if I wanted to establish if a table or a view existed in Database, can I filter the Database for that table or view? I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Ok no worries - and it's stu, as in stuart ;)